# preg_replace_callback not applied to every html string

Tags: php

hello i've edited a simple function to change characters with their greec similar look .here the code

```
function homographit($string){

$alphabet = array("A", "B", "C", "E", "H", "J", "K", "M", "N", "O", "P", "S", "T", "X", "Y", 
"a", "b", "c", "e", "i", "j", "k", "o", "p", "r", "s", "v", "x", "y");    


$Greec   = array("\u0391", "\u0392", "\u0421", "\u0395", "\u0397", "\u0408", "\u039A", "\u039C", "\u039D", "\u039F", "\u03A1", "\u0405", 
"\u03A4", "\u03A7", "\u03A5", "\u0430", "\u042C", "\u0441", "\u0435", "\u0456", "\u0458", "\u03BA", "\u03BF", "\u03C1", "\u0433", "\u0455", 
"\u03BD", "\u03C7", "\u0443");   

$newstring = str_replace($alphabet, $Greec, $string);
return json_decode('"'.$newstring.'"', true);
}


$html = '<html><h1> some text i want to replace</h1><p>some stuff i want to replace </p>';

$text_to_echo =  preg_replace_callback(
    "/(<([^.]+)>)([^<]+)(<\\/\\2>)/s", 
    function($matches){
$text= homographit($matches[3]);
        return $matches[1].$text.$matches[4];
    }, 
    $html
);
echo $text_to_echo;
```

for this html string it's ok to change all text:

```
$html = '<html><h1> some text i want to replace</h1><p>some stuff i want to replace </p>';
```

but if i change with this one:

```
$html = '<html> <body> <p> Lina has <span>blue</span>eyes and my bruno has <span>dark green </span> eyes</p></body></html>';
```

my fucntion homographit is applied to a party of text .

any nhelp to change the pattern in preg_replace_callback to apply change to any text in html string ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the RegEx to not match a complete html tag of the form `<tag>some text</tag>`. Instead change it to look for any text between the character `>` and `<`. The RegEx should look like this:

```
/(?<=>)([^>]+)(?=<)/
```

With the changed RegEx you might need to change the callback function to work with the correct group matches. Also see the example on https://regex101.com/r/xk2kDg/1, notice the green selections in the example input.